# Why am I seeing multiply rows from database

Tags: php, database, error-handling, rows

Here is my code, it is connected with database as well but see the image, why does it show 2 times the same ID and other rows?

Here is an screen shoot what it shows :/

[image]

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['usr'];
        // get results from database
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlist, tz_members WHERE Byuser='$username'") 
                or die(mysql_error());  


        echo "<table id='table_example'><thead>";
        echo "<tr><th width='1%'>ID</th><th width='10%'>Kengtar(<i><span style='color: blue'>i</span></i>/<i>ja</i>)</th><th width='5%'>Kenga</th><th width='7%'>Albumi</th><th width='2%'>Data</th></tr>";
        echo "</thead><tbody>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<th>#' . $row['ID'] . '</th>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Kengtar'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Kenga'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Albumi'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Data'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Thank you if anyone tries to help me, im new in php codind stuff :S

Comment: can we get screenshots of your db. i'll guess that you have these rows in both the tables you're querying in your sql statement.

Comment: Sure but i can explain here playlist has (ID, Kengtar, Kenga, Linku, Data, Byuser) and tz_members has just memberID, username password

Comment: Thank you it's solved, i had just to remove tz_members from selectoin im happy YEAH hahahaha thank you very much <3 ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query did a Cartesian product of 2 tables. Instead, you need to join the tables with a condition like this:

```
select * 
from playlist a, 
     tz_members b
where Byuser='$username' 
      and a.id = b.id
```

Of course, you need to change `a.id = b.id` to the actual relation.